# Laravel calling seeder in subdirectory - Class not found

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, laravel-8, laravel-seeding

Laravel (currently 8.12 | php 7.4.14) started throwing errors a few days ago when I try to execute a seeder in a subdirectory via `Artisan::call`.

On bash this command works fine:

```sh
php artisan db:seed --class=Database\\Seeders\\Testing\\StagingTestDataSeeder
```

But I want to execute it as:

```php
Artisan::call("db:seed --class=Database\\Seeders\\Testing\\StagingTestDataSeeder");
```

The result is: `Target class [Database\\Seeders\\DatabaseSeedersTestingStagingTestDataSeeder] does not exist.` Which is absolutely correct as there are no namespace delimiters in the argument. Beacuse there are no delimiters in the argument, the `getSeeder`-method just concats the argument to the base namespace of database seeders
(see below `if (strpos($class, '\\') === false) {`).

Because it works on bash I don't thinkt that there are any mistakes with namespace or file location.
I dumped some data in the `Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\SeedCommand.php::66`

```php
/**
     * Get a seeder instance from the container.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Seeder
     */
    protected function getSeeder()
    {
        $class = $this->input->getArgument('class') ?? $this->input->getOption('class');
        dump($this->options());
        dump($this->arguments());
        dump($class);
        if (strpos($class, '\\') === false) {
            $class = 'Database\\Seeders\\' . $class;
        }

        if (
            $class === 'Database\\Seeders\\DatabaseSeeder' &&
            !class_exists($class)
        ) {
            $class = 'DatabaseSeeder';
        }

        return $this->laravel->make($class)
            ->setContainer($this->laravel)
            ->setCommand($this);
    }
```

which prints this:

```php
array:10 [▼
  "class" => "DatabaseSeedersTestingStagingTestDataSeeder"
  "database" => null
  "force" => false
  "help" => false
  "quiet" => false
  "verbose" => false
  "version" => false
  "ansi" => null
  "no-interaction" => false
  "env" => null
]
```

```php
array:2 [▼
  "command" => "db:seed"
  "class" => null
]
```

```php
"DatabaseSeedersTestingStagingTestDataSeeder"
```

Somehow the escaped backslash does not reach the getSeeder-method of the SeedCommand-class.
I know that I could load the class with pure PHP via require or add the deep namespace to the `composer.json`. But as this is not the intended use by laravel I want to figure out how to do it with onboard functionality.

---- a few tests later ----

I figured out that I can pass the class/ namespace value as option (with `--class=`) as well as argument (just the namespace) to the `SeedCommand.php`. So  `Artisan::call("db:seed Database\\\\Seeders\\\\Testing\\\\StagingTestDataSeeder");` works now.

Can someone explain what happens there? I'm totally confused why I need to pass the double amount of backslashes. It seems that the argument is interpreted twice or something.
Was the `SeedCommand` recently updated?

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
Artisan::call('db:seed', ['--class' => Database\Seeders\Testing\StagingTestDataSeeder]);
```

look more details https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Comment: OK, thanks. That seems to work.
But can you explain why the syntax from the bash call stoped working when called programmatically?

Comment: I did not know need to check